# Use SSL with Gearman/PHP and YouTube

Tags: php, ssl, https, gearman

Honestly, I do not know very much about SSL and certificates (letting aside to use https, that is). I'd like to assure that my PHP script *always* uses SSL to transfer files to YouTube (via the Google API client). How do I establish a secure connection to YouTube (is a certificate even needed?) ?
Underlying is a Gearman server (and I did find [this link](http://gearman.info/gearmand/ssl.html) on their website, it seems to be for your **own** server, however), if this is of any matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to upload the files to a third party server, in this case YouTube, this is as easy as using the HTTPS version of the URL provided by the service.

In other words, you just need to make sure you perform the API requests [using the client](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries) via HTTPS. Checking the documentation, it seems quite evident the clients are using the base URL

```
https://www.googleapis.com/
```

which is indeed HTTPS. Therefore, there is no extra step required on your side.